# Dirichlet domain complexity

Tags: nt.number-theory, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose I have a subgroup of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ given by explicit matrix generators, and my goal in life is to construct a Dirichlet domain (for, say, everyone's favorite basepoint $\sqrt{-1}$). Is there any known estimate on how big a piece of the orbit I need to compute?

Comment: Wow, someone downvoted this question! It must be really trivial...

Comment: Igor: Did you check J. Gilman, Algorithms, complexity and discreteness criteria in PSL(2, C), J. Anal. Math. 73 (1997), pp. 91–114. There she estimates complexity of Riley's algorithm, but maybe only from below, I do not remember...